# run MySQL server self-contained and as a user

Tags: linux, mysql

I'd like to run a MySQL server on a machine on which I have no/few permissions, and so I would like all data and all sockets to be contained in a single directory, and I'd obviously like to run it as user instead of as a service. This is all on linux.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a lot of info on how to do this out there if you Google for it. (Or visit the `man` page.)

[From the MySQL online documentation page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html):

On Unix, the MySQL server mysqld can be started and run by any user. However, you should avoid running the server as the Unix root user for security reasons. To change `mysqld` to run as a normal unprivileged Unix user `user_name`, you must do the following:

1. Stop the server if it is running (use `mysqladmin shutdown`).
2. Change the database directories and files so that `user_name` has privileges to read and write files in them (you might need to do this as the Unix root user): `shell> chown -R user_name /path/to/mysql/datadir` If you do not do this, the server will not be able to access databases or tables when it runs as `user_name.` If directories or files within the MySQL data directory are symbolic links, `chown -R` might not follow symbolic links for you. If it does not, you will also need to follow those links and change the directories and files they point to.
3. Start the server as user `user_name.` Another alternative is to start mysqld as the Unix root user and use the `--user=user_name` option. `mysqld` starts up, then switches to run as the Unix user `user_name` before accepting any connections.
4. To start the server as the given user automatically at system startup time, specify the user name by adding a user option to the `[mysqld] group` of the `/etc/my.cnf` option file or the `my.cnf` option file in the server's data directory. For example:

> [mysqld]
>
> user=user_name

If your Unix machine itself is not secured, you should assign passwords to the MySQL root accounts in the grant tables. Otherwise, any user with a login account on that machine can run the mysql client with a `--user=root` option and perform any operation. (It is a good idea to assign passwords to MySQL accounts in any case, but especially so when other login accounts exist on the server host.)

Comment: Doesn't answer the question